# Wordpress - how to edit filter on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress 5.6.1 install careerfy theme I want to remove some filter on theme.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M6lW.png)

Please help me with the mentioned issue.
Filter option not found on theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Appearance > Customize** in the WordPress Administration Screens. Click the **Widget** menu in the Theme Customizer to access to the Widget Customize Screen. Click the down arrow of Widget Area to list the already registered Widgets. Click **Add a Widget** button at the bottom of sidebar.

[Widgets support article](https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-widgets/)

Comment: thank you for replying but if i want to delete some filter how can I delete from widgets  ? Ex: above mentioned photo i want to remove gender, and edit qualification widgets so how can we do ?

Comment: Do you have documentation for careerfy theme? The one you have mentioned in a screenshot seems to be managed from the Theme options or some other way. So better to study documentation as this is theme specific